# How to move a file with a complicated filename in python

Tags: python

I am trying to do `$ mv <file> ..` in a python script using `subprocess.call()`. I am able to do this on 'normal' filenames, but on certain filenames it does not work. I do not have control of the filenames that are given to the script. Here is an example:

M filename is `"ITunes ES Film Metadata_10_LaunchTitles(4th Batch)_08_20_2010.XLS"`

When I try and do the command directly into the python prompt and drag the file into it, this is what I get:

```
>>> /Users/David/Desktop/itunes_finalize/TheInventionOfLying_CSP/
    ITunes\ ES\ Film\ Metadata_10_LaunchTitles\(4th\ Batch\)_08_20_2010.XLS

No such file or directory
```

How would I go about moving this file in a python script?

**Update:**

Thanks for the answers, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.[xX][lL][sS]')):
    shutil.move(file, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), os.path.pardir))
```

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess.call()` instead of `shutil.move` or `os.rename`?

Comment: He probably didn't know about it...  I think the tone of his question addresses this ignorance.  Not everyone is used to a language with "batteries included." ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess` is not the best way to go here.  For example, what if you're on an operating system that  isn't POSIX compliant?

Check out the [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module.

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.move(src, dest)
```

If finding the actual string for the filename is hard you can use `glob.glob` to pattern match what you want. For example, if you're running the script/prompt from the directory with the .XLS file in question you could do the following.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*ITunes*.XLS')
```

You'll get a list back with all the file strings that fit that pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using `subprocess` and spawning a new process, use `shutil.move()` to just do it in Python.  That way, the names won't be reinterpreted and there will be little chance for error.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces, parens, etc. are the shell's problem. They don't require escaping in Python provided you don't pass them to a shell.

```
open('*WOW!* Rock&Roll(uptempo).mp3')
```

Comment: While I thinks this is great advice about the shell, it doesn't directly face the question of "How would I go about moving this file in a python script?"